# Dotenv - Accessing environment variable that starts with a number and includes a dash

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

**Problem**

- I'm unable to access `clientID` value from `.env` file.
- Currently results with Node app crashing. It works when I manually input clientID value to setup.js (see setup.js - working version)

**Desired outcome**

- Be able to access `clientID` from `.env` using `process.env.clientID`

**.env file**

```
clientID=2454554545-fsfsdfg7sgfsg78gdf8g78gs7fs.apps.googleusercontent.com
clientSecret=AAAB-GDFGFG76FG87DSG8DGGFDGSFS
```

**setup.js - throws error**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './keys.env' });

{
    clientID: process.env.clientID, 
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret // ClientSecret works fine even though 
}
```

**setup.js - working version**

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: './keys.env' });

{
    clientID: '2454554545-fsfsdfg7sgfsg78gdf8g78gs7fs.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
    clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret
}
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: OAuth2Strategy requires a clientID option
```

Comment: tried single quoting the `clientID` in the `.env` file? `clientID='...'`

Comment: @Anuga Actually it doesnt work when I wrap it with quotes.

Comment: console.info/log(process.env) before the OAuth, and see what it outputs.